# Which setting can override indent size in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, indentation, text-indent, tab-size

My PhpStorm 2022.3.3 has [indent size for Markdown](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-style-markdown.html#tabs-and-indents) set to `4`. Yet, each time I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Editor (while editing regular GitHub's *README.md* file) I am clearly getting only **two** spaces:

[image]

What am I missing? Which setting can override the above?

Comment: Open the markdown file and show a screenshot of the status bar -- area where it has line ending symbol, caret position etc etc. It should show the indent size as well. Does it show `2` there? How does it look exactly? Does it show just a number or a number with an asterisk? If the later one then it's easy to solve.

Comment: @LazyOne I hope that the "asterisk" is easy to solve! Because know I (knowing nothing about phpStorm, just starting to use it) am starting to think that there is some magic happening here. Yesterday (when asking) it had `4` in configuration and was adding `2` spaces. To day, **on a very same file** it shows `3 spaces*` in the status bar and adds **three** spaces (?)...

Comment: So it shows `3 spaces *` there? As far as I know / how it works here on my PC: the asterisk tells that the corresponding IDE option is overridden. Most likely it's your `.editorconfig` file (which is absolutely expected -- the whole nature of such files).

Comment: IF I'm right here (should be) then your options are (3 of them) : **1)** Recommended: go through all `.editorconfig` files that you have in your project (the folder with the problematic file and up) and change the appropriate option -- look at `indent_size` option. You can click on that `3 spaces *` area in the status bar and it will show you an extra menu which you may use as well.

Comment: **2)** Disable EditorConfig files support for this project via that menu; **3)** Disable EditorConfig files support altogether. `.editorconfig` are very common thing these days, so it's better make them work properly. Plus, they allow to do certain things that standard IDE setting cannot do (more granular control -- only apply certain things to specific file type or even a specific file/folder)

Comment: P.S. It's weird to see an indent of `2` and now `3`. Unless you have been editing that `.editorconfig` file yourself while trying to solve this issue... (or done by another person if you work in a team and use VCS).

Comment: P.S. The IDE also also has an option to detect the right indent size and symbol used (TAB vs SPACE) automatically from the current file (first few lines). But for me this option did not work properly when it was just introduced (many many years ago). So I have it disabled since then and cannot advise how it would look in the status bar. But double check it as well if `.editorconfig` will not be the reason.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information and any attempt to resolve my issue. Unfortunately this is a false shot, because neither this folder / repository nor any of my repositories has _.editorconfig_ files. In all 25+ repositories I have found just five of such files and all of them where in _vendor_ folder, auto-populated by Composer. So, no need to touch them, as I won't be editing (locally) any of the vendor-related or external libraries files.

Comment: The above still suggests that there is a file that makes those changes (unless it's all solely because of the "auto-detect indents" option). I would re-enable EditorConfig support and see how it behaves. If it still shows the same then you clearly have `.editorconfig` files somewhere that you may be missing in your searches. Remember that `.editorconfig` from subfolders or sibling folder (`vendor` etc) do not affect files in parent/higher level folders hence you can ignore them there.